# PHP: How to make a select box work and how to stop drop down menu selection from resetting to first option on button click

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, listbox

I'm still relatively new to PHP and I am having some issues.

I have a paramaterized query set up that uses a selected Region and selected Subsystem to print a report. The user selects the Region from a select box with 5 regions hard coded. Then they select a Subsystem from a drop down menu that queries rows from a database.

I have not copied all the code below, just the relevant parts.

Here is my code on the functions page for the listbox:

```
<?php

function listbox($query, $name, $previous, $db){

 $result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("Query ($query) is incorrect!");
 print "<select name=\"$name\">\n";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ //Table body
 if($row[0] == $previous){
 print "\t<option value=\"$row[0]\" selected=\"selected\">$row[0]</option>\n";
 }else{
 print "\t<option value=\"$row[0]\">$row[0]</option>\n";
 }
 }
 print "</select>";
 }
?>
```

Here is my code on the index page that calls the function page:

```
<?php

$default = "";
$previous = "";
$name4 = "region";
$name1 = "sub";


?>

    <select name="<?php print $name4 ?>" size="5">
    <option value="Option 1" selected>West</option>
         <option value="Option 2">North Central</option>
         <option value="Option 3">South Gulf</option>
          <option value="Option 4">North East</option>
    <option value="Option 5">South Atlantic</option>
</select>

<?php listbox($SubsystemListbox_strSQL, $name1, $previous, $db) ?>


 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){


$ByRegionCap_strSQL = "CALL `unit_costs_db`.`Subsystem_Average_Capital_Costs`('{$_POST[$name4]}', '{$_POST[$name1]}');";

}
```

as of right now, the region select box doesn't work at all, so I have been using code similar to the subsystem listbox:
  listbox($RegionListbox_strSQL, $name4, $previous, $db)

Also, right now after the submit button is clicked, both selected option values reset to the first value in the dropdown. I would like to have both boxes remain showing their previously selected values after the submit button has been clicked.

If anyone has any ideas on how to help, please let me know!!

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

When you reload your page, all your HTML elements go back to the initial state.
You have to get the content of the select via HTTP POST and set it the right option to "selected"

Answer (score 0):

do you submit the form to the same script?

then you could do smth like:

```
<select name="<?php print $name4 ?>" size="5">
  <option value="Option 1" <?=$_POST[$name4] == 'West' ? 'selected' : ''?>>West</option>
  <option value="Option 2" <?=$_POST[$name4] == 'North Central' ? 'selected' : ''?>>North Central</option>
  <option value="Option 3" <?=$_POST[$name4] == 'South Gulf' ? 'selected' : ''?>>South Gulf</option>
  ...
</select>
```

if it is another script you may save the data in the session and access over $_SESSION instead of $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be relevant, but the first thing that I see is the way you print your options:

```
print "\t<option value=\"$row[0]\">$row[0]</option>\n";
```

PHP won`t let you do this for an array. You need to break your string:

```
print "\t<option value=\"".$row[0]."\">".$row[0]."</option>\n";
```

Or use curly braces:

```
print "\t<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[0]}</option>\n";
```

To preserver the selected values you need to keep track of them and manually select the needed values. In your case - check if the **$previous** variable is properly filled with data.